# How do I start an android activity from a .cpp script?

Tags: android, c++, c

Say I am using C and C++ and I want to execute a script made in C from within a terminal emulator in android so that it opens an activity, a GUI. Is it possible? and how do I do it?

I wouldn't care using assembly, my tablet's processor is ARMv7. if the answer is somewhere in there.

Comment: What does "terminal emulation" mean? In an app running in Android, through a shell with root access, or through adb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start an Android Activity that same way you would in Java, by constructing an appropriate [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) instance and then calling [`Context.startActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).  The main difference is that you need to thunk into Java via [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) in order to do so from C or C++.

Look into functions like `GetMethodID` and `CallVoidMethod` within the `JNIEnv` class—using those, you can call a Java function from C++ code.  Then you just need a small amount of Java glue code to do what you want.

Comment: This answers the part about starting the activity via JNI, but it's unclear if @MrFunky wants the emulator to be launched from terminal on his computer?  You might have to add more to this answer.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention I wanted to do it from a shell in the device, no debug, no emulator. And yeah, I'd have to get dalvik to start the thing, well, thanks a lot!